# Why does row count return more than the number of rows with data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have added a new sheet and imported Excel data in that sheet.

```
iteration=datatable.GetSheet(3).GetRowCount
```

There are four rows in my sheet. The script is running continuously after the 4th iteration taking blank data.

When I displayed total count writing as `msgbox iteration`, it is showing 999 rows

Comment: i'm here because of tag [tag:leanft] but doesn't seem related. why did you include that tag?

Comment: Try deleting blank rows in the sheet. Select all rows below 4 rows rt click and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the rows after the 4º.

U can lock the script to run the iteration u wanna or just run one.

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpyrI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UsedRange`:

```
iteration = datatable.GetSheet(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count
```